Switch to second most recently used app in applescript
Is it possible in AppleScript to switch to the second most recently used app (what pressing Cmd-Tab would do)? How would I got about doing this?
One way is to simulate Cmd+tab key presses, but I am not sure this would be fool proof and I wonder if there's a better way

osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"
    key down command
    keystroke tab
    key up command
end tell'


I could not think of a scenario where a different behavior will happen when you press command + tab. To simplify the script, you can do:
tell application "System Events"
    key code 48 using {command down}
end tell

If you must use osascript (perhaps it is part of your shell script), you can write it like:
osascript \
    -e 'tell application "System Events"' \
    -e '    key code 48 using {command down}' \
    -e 'end tell'

